# How to enable block styles on admin page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I saw some examples where block styles successfully applied on custom admin page, but how to implement this. I tried  `wp_enqueue_style('wp-format-library')` but nothing. Using twenty-twenty-one theme.
[image]

```
<Panel header="Roles">
        <PanelBody>
          <PanelRow>
            <ToggleControl
              label="enable custom role"
              checked={enable}
              onChange={() => setEnable(!enable)}
            />
          </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
        <PanelBody>
          <PanelRow>
            <TabPanel
              tabs={[
                {
                  name: "tab1",
                  title: "Tab 1",
                  className: "tab-one",
                },
                {
                  name: "tab2",
                  title: "Tab 2",
                  className: "tab-two",
                },
              ]}
            >
              {(tab) => <p>{tab.title}</p>}
            </TabPanel>
          </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
      </Panel>
```

This what I got, without styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked when I enqueued `wp-edit-blocks` via `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
function enqueue_admin_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-edit-blocks' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_assets' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) hook.

> admin_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts and styles that are meant to be used in the administration panel. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

```php
function my_admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'my-admin-styles',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-admin.css'
    );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_style');
```

Comment: no I want block styles, i cant find this style file to extend it on custom admin page.

Comment: Maybe look into [`register_block_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_style/) and [`enqueue_block_styles_assets`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/enqueue_block_styles_assets/) as well.

Comment: no i dont want adding custom styles, i want block styles from wordpress to be enqueued on custom admin page. Wordpress uses load-styles.php to enqueue block styles on post.php & post-new.php pages. How to enable load-styles.php with block styles on custom admin page?

Comment: found wp-includes/css/dist/block-editor/style.css